# vba access run time error 3265

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am new to programming in VBA. I am trying to copy Form data from an existing form when I click on the `Copy Record` button. This is supposed to copy the current form data as a new record with a new `master_id` (that is autonumbered) and have `Brand` as blank field for them to fill in. I get a:

> Run Time Error 3265 "Item not found in this collection"

at the `new_master_id` that i created. I am not sure how to fix this problem. Any help is appreciated.

```
Private Sub Copy_Record_Click()

Dim RS As DAO.Recordset, C As Control
Dim FillFields As String, FillAllFields As Integer
Dim New_MASTER_ID As Integer
New_MASTER_ID = (DMax("[MASTER_ID]", "tbl_Drug_Master") + 1)
Dim BRAND As String
BRAND = ""

Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Name:="tbl_Drug_Master", Type:=RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)

With RS
    .AddNew
    ![MASTER_ID] = ![New_MASTER_ID] <--this is where the problem is...
    ![MASTER_KEY] = Me![MASTER_KEY]
    ![PRODUCT_CATEGORY] = Me![PRODUCT_CATEGORY]
    ![BRAND] = Me![BRAND]
    ![GENERIC] = Me![GENERIC]
    ![STUDY_NAME] = Me![STUDY_NAME]
    ![MANUFACTURER] = Me![MANUFACTURER]
    ![MASTER_COMMENTS] = Me![MASTER_COMMENTS]

    .Update

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Two things. As you have it, `New_MASTER_ID` is a VBA variable and not a field in recordset. Also, you cannot append to or update an autonumber field. If already an autonumber, let database handle it, so leave out of recordset handle.

Comment: I agree with @parfait here, just remove that problem line completely and the autonumber will be autogenerated. Also add `rs.close` and `set RS = nothing` when youre finished with your recordset

Comment: @Parfait - i took out the new_master_id field. I now get a error on the .Update saying that index or Primary Key cannot be blank. So how would i handle that issue with the master_id field being null?

Comment: @LiamH - i did what you said but received an error. Error was saying i cant put it in the With clause, that made sense to me. So i took it out and put it in after the End With and before the End Sub. Still received an error. Where would it go then? those 2 places made the most sense to me.

Comment: @vbnewbie is master_ID an autonumber? what are you doing with the `BRAND` string? ... I am unsure why you get this error. it should go after with and what error is it? maybe just try the `set RS = nothing` without the `rs.close`.

Comment: In `tbl_Drug_Master`, delete the current `master_id `field which probably is a regular number field. After saving changes, recreate the `master_id` field as autonumber and as primary key. Alternatively, use original code but reference VBA variable: ` ![MASTER_ID] = New_MASTER_ID `.

Comment: @LiamH  - master_id is autonumbered field and master_key is the PK field, in both tables. They are related to each other, main form has a subform called indications which then ties data from both forms together using master_key and master_id together. This is a job i was asked to take over and other person is gone. Lucky me. LiamH i tried just the rs=nothing after with end and that got same error as before. I dont want to drop those fields and rebuild it. Not sure how bad it would mess up this tool.

Comment: @LiamH - Brand is the name of the drug. it is set to be unique. No duplicates allowed. So i figured to set it to blank when copying over data and avoid that problem. Is that workable or i need to do something else.

Comment: @Parfait, LiamH - i was able to get rs.close and set rs=nothing to work. Now i get a 3022 error which relates to Indexed fields in tables. Can only have 1 indexed field from my research. master_id and master_key were both indexed. I changed master_id to be not indexed and now get an error saying it cannot be done. Almost all the tables are indexed with no duplicates on the PK of them. Some had also another indexed field set to yes(no duplicates) i changed those and i get the same issue. So i have to figure another way to copy the data into a new row by selecting current record using sql.

Answer (score 1):

ok so firstly, im not sure why the following are required:

```
dim c as control
Dim FillFields As String, FillAllFields As Integer
New_MASTER_ID = (DMax("[MASTER_ID]", "tbl_Drug_Master") + 1)
Dim BRAND As String
BRAND = ""
```

therefore I am leaving them out as part of this question because they appear unnecessary. Brand is not required because you are creating a new record and putting nothing in the brand field so it will remain blank.

I am also not too sure why you have 2 tables both that are the same? I think what should happen is that you simply copy the data to a new record in the same table.

You will see I have put a save record command in to the routine. other additions such as error handling is also recommended.

```
Private Sub Copy_Record_Click()
docmd.runcommand accmdsaverecord
Dim RS As Recordset

Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Name:="tbl_Drug_Master", Type:=RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)

  With RS
    .AddNew
       ![MASTER_KEY] = Me.MASTER_KEY.value
       ![PRODUCT_CATEGORY] = Me.PRODUCT_CATEGORY.value
       ![GENERIC] = Me.GENERIC.value
       ![STUDY_NAME] = Me.STUDY_NAME.value
       ![MANUFACTURER] = Me.MANUFACTURER.value
       ![MASTER_COMMENTS] = Me.MASTER_COMMENTS.value
    .Update 
  End With
Set RS = Nothing
End Sub
```

I was mistaken with my comment `rs.close` it would be `db.close` but you are using the `currentdb` and no reason to close it. This procedure will remain on the original record, if you want to go to the new record you will have to add a command like `docmd.gotorecord acdataform, , aclast` before the end of the routine.

Comment: i received an error on Brand. Error 3314, saying i must enter a name for Brand. This is set to be not null. I changed that to not required and then got a Run-time error of 3022. Which is would create duplicate data in the index values, primary key, or relationship.

Comment: the PK field Master_Key is the only field that doesnt allow duplicates.

Comment: im a bit confused now, I thought master_ID was the PK and autonumber? If master_key is the PK and no duplicates allowed then remove the line `![MASTER_KEY] = me.MASTER_KEY.value` because theres no need and it will cause this error.

Comment: sorry to confuse you from earlier. master_key is PK and master_id is autonumber. I took out what you said and got a different error now. Error 3058, Index or PK cannot contain a null value.

Comment: you could also consider a "composite key". I'm not sure if it is appropriate but will add a bit more ruling to your table. Have a look in to it, it may be useful were two individual fields can be duplicates but not together. in fact, is there already a composite index set up?

Comment: could this be because of the subform that goes with this main form? i have checked that table and that is not indexed. it does contain master_id, master_key as well.

Comment: whats the subform and whats the relationship between the two tables?

Comment: the main form has info it writes to the tbl_Drug_master table. The Indications subform writes to the tbl_Drug_Indications table. They are related by the master_key and master_id. they are tabs on the form and you can go back and forth on them as needed.

Comment: did you fix this issue? you don't need to link two tables by two different fields. usually the ID field is autonumber and PK and not seen by the user

Comment: yes i was able to fix the error. I was not bringing in all the fields for the form in the select statement.